# How to fix 'No valid export link available' error in SSPYRS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download a SSRS report using sspyrs but getting an error : 'No valid export link available'

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/018nw.png)
[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
import sspyrs
myrpt = sspyrs.report(r'http://10.168.2.245:9081/reports/report/SKF%20Stock%20Report(1)','myusername','mypass')
myrpt.directdown('F:\myfile', 'Excel')
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not use `requests`?

Comment: Thanks @WaketZheng for your concern. I am a noob in python.
I tried this:
import requests
url = 'http://username:pass@10.168.2.245:9081/Report/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FSKF%20Stock%20Report(1)'

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url)

output_file = r'F:\myfile.xlsx'

downloaded_file = open(output_file, 'wb')
for chunk in r.iter_content(1000):
    downloaded_file.write(chunk)

It returned an empty excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might not be the appropriate approach but for now this has solved my problem**

`from selenium import webdriver`

`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`

`options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`

**Changing the download directory**

`prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,"download.default_directory": r'F:\Reports\'',"directory_upgrade": True}`
`options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)`

`driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Alim\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)`

**passing the username and password**(username:password) **through url and rendering the report in Excel**(&rs%3AFormat=Excel)

`driver.get("http://username:password@10.168.2.245:9081/Report/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FSKF%20Stock%20Report(1)&rs%3AFormat=Excel")`

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
from requests import Session

host = 'https://cloud.digitalocean.com'
login_uri = '/login'
target_uri = '/projects'
s = Session()
s.auth = ('username', 'password')
s.get(host + login_uri)
r = s.get(host + target_uri)
r.raise_for_status()
print(len(r.content))
```

Comment: Thanks@WaketZheng. This is how I did it:
`from selenium import webdriver`
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
`options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`
`prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,"download.default_directory": r'F:\Reports\'',"directory_upgrade": True}`
`options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)`
`driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Alim\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)`
`driver.get("http://username:password@10.168.2.245:9081/Report/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FSKF%20Stock%20Report(1)&rs%3AFormat=Excel")`